# Passing variable to form action javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I have a form to update an entity called Equipment. This form must pass in the action the route '/' serial number of the equipment.

How can i pass the serial number of this entity?

This form is in a modal. See below:

```
<form
 name="editEquipmentForm"
 id="editEquipmentForm"
 class="form-horizontal"
 method="POST"
 action="/equipments/SERIALNUMBER"  <-- I need pass the serial here
>
```

I get the variable in another file called request.ejs. This file is included by the index.ejs, that has the modal.

Here's how i get the serialnumber:

```
function getEquipmentData(serialNumber) {
var serialNumber = serialNumber;
setEditInputs();
document.getElementById("serialnumber2").value = serialNumber;

$.ajax({
  url: "equipments/" + serialNumber,
  type: "get",
  success: function(response) {
    document.getElementById("sha1Curve2").value = response[0].sha1Curve;
    document.getElementById("equipmentName2").value =
      response[0].equipmentName;
    document.getElementById("position2").value = response[0].position;
    document.getElementById("idealRangeMin2").value =
      response[0].idealRangeMin;
    document.getElementById("idealRangeMax2").value =
      response[0].idealRangeMax;
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});}
```

This function is called when i open the modal.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: can you show us full HTML of FORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.forms.editEquipmentForm.action = '/equipments/' + serialNumber;
```

Or this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('editEquipmentForm');
form.action = '/equipments/' + serialNumber;
```

Comment: I used it too, very useful. Thank you